# Responsive use of the bootstrap form-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the problem with the form-group class of bootstrap

On https://jsfiddle.net/oursgris/7s2pgthy/#&togetherjs=9SHsiHc4oj

I extracted the problem

When I'm a small or medium device with that code. the line between "Statut" and "Etat" is smaller because I don't use the form-group class.

[image: xs]

on medium device I have the wanted result (and large also)

[image: md]

When I add

```
<div class="form-group">
```

between statut and etat, there is the space of from-group (a margin-bottom of 15px)

https://jsfiddle.net/oursgris/t4dt9avw/embedded/result/

but in that case the md and large add a line, how can I correct that behaviour ? I imagine that I missuse a css class

[image: md2]

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you need. You mentioned a line. What line?

Comment: well i'm sorry I figure it is complicated. the layout with the form-group is very cool with the margin-bottom. but I have some problem with one line. on large layout, I need to group 2 items on the same line but when I'm on xs or small layout, I'd like to put it on the line

Comment: I see. Just to be sure i understand, you are trying to avoid the label above the textbox layout in phone view?

Comment: yes it was a problem of use. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your JFiddle, I noticed a few things wrong with your form such as improper use of the  `form-group` class. I also reworked your classes to get the desired view I think you are looking for. If all you were looking for a was a inline form through out all the views, all you had to do was stay away from a 12 span class.

I worked out a [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrKyW) for you in a Code Pen

p.s. you didn't need that empty column div (unless you are using that to programmatically display something in it via JQuery. Other than that, the use of form-group takes care of isolating that label and input field in its own row.

Comment: thank you I din't understood how to do. it is rly a great help for me. and your tip for the empty div is really good ;p